# Using Groovy in ODI to set the Subscriber for a data source

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

We have a requirement to bulk change the subscriber on many mappings but I’m finding it difficult constructing the correct method calls. I’m looping through my mapping  list but not sure how to change the subscriber for each mapping. I have this code structure in my Groovy script:

```
//Created with ODI Studio

import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

import java.awt.FlowLayout as FL
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel
import javax.swing.BoxLayout as BXL

import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiProjectFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiProject;
import oracle.odi.domain.adapter.project.IKnowledgeModule.ProcessingType;
import oracle.odi.domain.project.finder.IOdiFolderFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.project.OdiFolder;
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.finder.IMappingFinder;
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.Mapping;
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.component.Dataset;
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.component.DatastoreComponent;
import oracle.odi.interfaces.interactive.support.InteractiveInterfaceHelperWithActions;
import oracle.odi.interfaces.interactive.IInteractiveInterfaceHelperWithActions;
import oracle.odi.core.persistence.transaction.ITransactionStatus;
import oracle.odi.core.persistence.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;
import oracle.odi.domain.mapping.physical.MapPhysicalNode;

//**********************************************************

// Careful, this is the project CODE, not the project name (all caps, no spaces)
myProject = "PROJECT"  // CODE of the ODI project where subscribers have to be replaced 
myFolder = "TEST FOLDER" // Folder where subscribers have to be replaced 
NewSubscriberName="TEST_SUBSCRIBER"  // Name of the new Subscriber that will replace the old one
MappingNamePattern="MAP_"  // Any part of the mapping name, if there is a pattern. Leave blank to process all mappings. 
// Example for patterns: "LOAD_" will process mapping LOAD_CUSTOMERS and PRELOAD_CUSTOMER but not LOADER_PRECURSOR

//--------------------------------------
// Build the list of available Folders

def getFoldersList(projectCode){
  folders = []
  foldersList = ff.findByProject(projectCode)

  for (folder in foldersList){
    folders.add(folder.getName())
    //println(folder.getName())
  }

  folders.sort()

  return folders
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------
// Main processing 
// First, retrieve the ODI studio connection to the repository
txnDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
tm = odiInstance.getTransactionManager();
tme = odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager()
txnStatus = tm.getTransaction(txnDef);

// Create a few shortcuts for the finders
pf = (IOdiProjectFinder)odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(OdiProject.class);
ff = (IOdiFolderFinder)odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(OdiFolder.class);
mapf = (IMappingFinder) odiInstance.getTransactionalEntityManager().getFinder(Mapping.class); 

// Locate the folder in the project
OdiFolder folder = null;
folderColl = ff.findByName(myFolder, myProject)
if (folderColl.size() == 1)
  folder = folderColl.iterator().next();

if (folder == null) {
   println("*** Could not find folder named\""+myFolder+"\"")
   exit
}

//--------------------------------------
// Retrieve all mappings in that folder
def OdiMappingsList = mapf.findByProject(myProject, folder.getFolderId())
println("*** Processing mappings for Project \""+myProject+"\", Folder \"" + myFolder+"\"")

//--------------------------------------
// For each mapping, do the folowing:
// - print mapping name
// - check if mapping name matched search string. If not, print 'no action' and get to the next mapping
// - if we have a name match, replace Subscriber with the new value.

for (map in OdiMappingsList){
    println("*******\nMapping: " + map.getName())
    bSubscriberChanged=false        
    // Make sure that the mapping matches the names we are looking for 
    if (map.getName().contains(MappingNamePattern)){
        // Set the subscriber
        sources = map.getSources()
        for (sourceDS in sources) {
           --- I NEED TO SET THE SUBSCRIBER HERE ---
           bSubscriberChanged=true
        }
    } else {// No match on mapping name
        println ("Skipped mapping: name does not contain \"" + MappingNamePattern +"\"")
    }
    if (bSubscriberChanged){
        // Persist the changes in the cache
        tme.persist(map);
    }
}//Mapping

// Commit the changes in the repository
tm.commit(txnStatus);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: without some code I don't think the community will be to help you, try to edit the question so you can get some answers

Comment: Ok no worries. I shall do that. I’m just looking for the set of classes/methods that deal with setting the subscriber value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a list of the source components of your mapping by using [getSources](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/IMapComponentOwner.html#getSources--) from IMapComponentOwner (which is implemented by Mapping).
These source components should be of type [DatastoreComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/reference-java-api/oracle/odi/domain/mapping/component/DatastoreComponent.html) which has a method to set the JournalizedFiler.

That would be something like this (couldn't test it yet) :

```
srcComps = map.getSources()
srcComps.each() { srcComp ->
    if (srcComp.isJournalized()) {
        srcComp.setJournalizedFilter("JRN_SUBSCRIBER = '"+NewSubscriberName+"'")
    }
}
```

Note that this code is only changing the filter if the component is set for journalization.

If you current journalized filters are more complex than that (e.g. include a date filter), you would need to use   getJournalizedFilter() and parse the result to only replace the subscriber name instead of overwriting the whole filter.

Comment: This is brilliant. It solved my problem although I did need to use isDatastoreJournalized instead of isJournalized. For some reason isJournalized was returning false on all my sources. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh that's weird but thanks for the feedback. Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer if it fully solved your problem ;).